# Rails Console Help Needed HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

I'm trying to figure out the command to update my roles_users model using the console. Am using cancan with devise and I'm trying to set up my seeds.rb. I wanted to test first.

My users have many roles and vice versa. Everything is working fine and my roles_users table has been populated.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to update a user in the console.

I can see from my development log the following happens:

```
INSERT INTO "roles_users" ("role_id", "user_id") VALUES (3, 1)
```

How can I do exactly this in the console??

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You should just be able to get a user, change its role, and save it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`User.find(user_id).roles << Role.find(role_id)`

Comment: Straight and to the point. Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even know where to start Jx